# BIRT - Two conditions for a string/dataset row

Tags: birt

I am new to birt editor.
In one of our expressions, it is checking for a `NULL` value of a dataset row and displaying it if it is not null.

```
(null==dataSetRow["XTDATA"]?"":dataSetRow["XTDATA"].substr(0,12))+'
```

How do I add another expression to this one, that if the data is of value `N/A`, to show as blank?

Comment: why don't you use : 
'if(dataSetRow["XTDATA"] != null){
      dataSetRow["XTDATA"].substr(0,12));
}else { 
      ""
}'

OR 'null!=dataSetRow["XTDATA"]?dataSetRow["XTDATA"].substr(0,12)):""'